# Overriding Mage_Wishlist_IndexController in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, wishlist

Hi i am trying to override magento wishlist **IndexController**. I have followed all steps but its not working here is my code and files path

> app\code\local\XS4Arabia\Wishlist\etc\config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>  
    <modules>      
        <XS4Arabia_Wishlist>          
            <version>0.1.0</version>      
        </XS4Arabia_Wishlist>  
    </modules>    
    <frontend>      
        <routers>          
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                  <modules>
                    <XS4Arabia_Wishlist before="Mage_Wishlist">XS4Arabia_Wishlist</XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
                  </modules>
                </args>
          </wishlist>      
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app\code\local\XS4Arabia\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php

```
    require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Wishlist') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
    class XS4Arabia_Wishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController
    {
      public function sendAction()
       {
        die('local');
       }
    }
```

> app\etc\modules\XS4arabia_Wishlist.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: I have tried your code on my local and it is working absolutely fine. Try flushing cache and check again. If it still doesn't work check if there is any other extension which already has re-written wishlist controller.

Comment: Its not working i just installed fresh magento without any extension

Comment: Try after adding depends tag in activation file.

Comment: can you please share your files its still not working i want to see how you did..

Comment: I didn't do any thing extra, copied your code and flush the cache, and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty small change

> Just replace the file name XS4arabia_Wishlist.xml to
>   XS4Arabia_Wishlist.xml

As per the conversation in comments, the working code is added below.

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </XS4Arabia_Wishlist>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: still not working..

Comment: Change module name "Wishlist" to unique string, for example "CustomWishlist".

Comment: Some times i am facing issues with core modules naming convention.

Comment: still not working bro i recently override checkout controller with same setting don't know why this one is not working

Comment: You can try the updated answer, it is working for me. the missing part is unnecessary spaces in XS4Arabia_Wishlist.xml.